# Calling Controller Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to call an MVC controller via ajax from a view.  The javascript I have is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ItemsCountActionViewPartial", "Catalogue-Item-Items")',
    type: "Post",
    $('@Model').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#totalResults").html(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
})
```

The controller is being called, but the razor model I am attempting to pass the controller isn't being passed correctly.  In the controller it is null but I have verified that it is not null at the time I make the ajax call.  The controller code is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ItemsCountActionViewPartial(CatalogueFindHelper finder)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get(LibraryGeneral.DEFAULT_LOCATION_COOKIE);

    int? val = cookie == null ? null : (int.Parse(cookie.Value) as int?);
    int numResults = 0;

    using (LibraryEntities db = new LibraryEntities())
    {
        foreach (CatalogueView view in finder.CatalogueViews)
            numResults += db.Items.Count(x => x.CatalogueItemID == view.CatalogueItemID);

        foreach (VirtualKitsView view in finder.VirtualKitViews)
            numResults += db.VirtualKitItems.Count(x => x.VirtualKitID == view.VirtualKitID);
    }

    return PartialView(numResults);
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: When I change the data to data: `$('@Model').serialize()` it no longer gets passed as null but the model is empty.  I updated my code to reflect this change.

Comment: What does your rendered javascript look like? What does your `CatalogueFindHelper` class look like?

Comment: do you have a controller named `Catalogue-Item-Items`? Because that's not a valid name for a C# class

Comment: also `$('@Model').serialize() `will probably not work. you should be using `$('#myForm').serialize()`

Comment: The controller name is "Catalogue_Item_Items" the dashes are in for SEO purposes.  It is handled, this isn't the problem as mentioned the function in the controller gets called, the parameter being null is the problem.

Comment: I don't have a form, and I need the values from my model.  The model is what i need to pass.

Comment: you should create a form, even if it's all hidden fields. try doing `console.log($('@Model').serialize());`  and you'll see what you're trying to send. I bet it's not what you want it to be.

Comment: I ended up figuring out a different way to do it, but answers are still welcome as I may need to do it in the future and it would be nice for anyone else having a similar issue to use this as a reference.